# Conditional Formatting not applying to all the cells in a given range

Tags: excel, excel-online

I have an issue in Excel online where my conditional formatting is not applied to the given cell range.

[image]

I have tried using absolute cell ranges as well, but for some reason excel online keeps overriding them back to relative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following instead as the Formular:

> =$P5=75%